# Why won't my android application open/start?

Tags: android

When someone installs my app from the app store, the Open button (usually found next to the uninstall button upon installation completion) is grayed out, and the application cannot be found in their app drawer.

Also, when I execute from Eclipse choosing Default Activity, it says in the console that it installed the APK, but it does not start. If I select the Splash activity as the default activity in the run configuration, it runs without a hitch, but I still cannot find it in my app drawer afterwards. Help would be appreciated c:

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.meteorfiber.gangnamstyle.Splash"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.meteorfiber.gangnamstyle.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.meteorfiber.gangnamstyle.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.meteorfiber.gangnamstyle.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Splash:

```
package com.meteorfiber.gangnamstyle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class Splash extends Activity {

private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    boolean isSplashEnabled = sp.getBoolean("isSplashEnabled", true);

    if (isSplashEnabled) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Splash.this.finish();

                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    } else {

        finish();
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
        Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
    }
}
 }
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.meteorfiber.gangnamstyle;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer ourSong;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(new GameView(this));
    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.song);
    ourSong.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // preventing default implementation previous to
        // android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSong.release();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your intent filter for your starting activity to

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

The android launcher along with the settings activity try to find this intent-filter in your application in order to launch the activity. If it can't be found, your activity cannot be launched with a typical launcher and won't be displayed.

Comment: @Cygwinnian - Battle of the keyboards!